# Can Tutorial "Dual Boot Windows 7 & Ubuntu 12.04" Used for Dual Booting Windows 8 & Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: boot, windows

I previously used [this tutorial](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/dual-boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/) to dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 perfectly. Now I have upgraded my Windows 7 to Windows 8. And I would like to do a fresh install (and start all over again like the tutorial) of Ubuntu 12.10 replacing existing Ubuntu 12.04. I like the way the tutorial presents thus can anyone kindly let me know if the tutorial is compatible with what I wanna do now?

I have tried doing little research whether this has been asked, but all I got are not too similar to my question, if there are topics like this I do apologise and feel free to close it.

Hope to hear from the community. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: Not going to add an answer because I don't really know, but it should work as long as you account for UEFI (by either not using/having it, or making other arrangements)

Comment: I think that you can only shrink your partition, and in Ubuntu instalator select "Install Ubuntu analogize Windows". BTW in Windows 8 I don't know how to select "manage"

You can also boot from Ubuntu USB/DVD, select "try Ubuntu", open gParted and shrink partition there.

Comment: Hi coteyr & kubahaha, I have now installed Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 8 side by side with no issues. Decided to stick with Ubuntu 12.04 (did a clean install). Thank you guys for responding my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Windows 8 but the principle should be the same.

But since you already had Ubuntu on this machine, it *might* be that the partitioning is still there, unless you installed Windows 8 on the entire disc.

However, upgrading Windows would have erased Grub (the bootloader) from the MBR.

If this is the case, then you can recover your present Ubuntu 12.04 by booting from an Ubuntu live DVD, install boot-repair, and fix Grub.

Then you can upgrade Ubuntu instead of installing from scratch.

In the case you repartitioned your disc during Windows 8 upgrade then the lin you mentioned should be the way to go.

Comment: Hi, I decided to do a clean install for Ubuntu was because my Ubuntu packages were broken. I have now clean installed Ubuntu 12.04 (stick with it due to LTS) and Windows 8 side by side. Thank you for your efforts :D